# valid memory limit test

Tags: php, memory-management, memory-limit

I´m having trouble with a crashing ION-Cube module.
The module imports csv data into our database, but if the csv file is to large (15+M)
the result is a internal server error.

The support told me my server does not have enough RAM to run the module.
The server has 1gb RAM built in  so I wrote a **simple** test script to check if ini_set works.

```
<pre>
<?php 
function tryAlloc($megabyte){
    echo "try allocating {$megabyte} megabyte...";
    $dummy = str_repeat("-",1048576*$megabyte);
    echo "pass.";
    echo "Usage: " . memory_get_usage(true)/1048576; 
    echo " Peak: " . memory_get_peak_usage(true)/1048576;
    echo "\n";
}   
for($i=10;$i<1000;$i+=50){
    $limit = $i.'M';
    ini_set('memory_limit', $limit); 
    echo "set memory_limit to {$limit}\n"; 
    echo "memory limit is ". ini_get("memory_limit")."\n";
    tryAlloc($i-10);
}

?>
</pre>
```

This runs without any problems.
Are there any major flaws in this test? We are having lots of trouble with this module and  the support keeps telling us that the problem is our server. -.-

PS: No I can not access php.ini. No I can not use .htaccess to set the memory limit.
No I have no way to edit fix/debug the module.

Comment: Just because you can allocate 1GiB of RAM, doesn't mean that it is enough for the Module. Can you trace/debug the Internal Server Error so that you get further informations? There could be many factors here, f.e. a memory leak in the module.

Comment: @Bobby No I have no read access to the error logs -.- I really hate our provider. I wrote a mail to the support and asked them to give me read access but that was in january....last time our manages server crashed it took them 72 hours to get it online again :/

Comment: @Oliver A.: Maybe this would be a good moment to convince Management that you need a new provider/hosting solution?

Comment: @Bobby lol we just changed our provider! Spend days looking for good offers, reading reviews and asking customer support for details, In the end the mangment choose one that was not even on my list because the first 3 month are free -.-

Comment: @Oliver A.: My deepest sympathy...my best bet is to get a local test server going (if possible) and monitor the module in there.

Comment: @Olive A I think you should consider looking for different employment if the management is so concerned for short term gains. Even though their 'expert' (you) recommends a certain solution, they pick another solution because it's cheaper for the first three months... they may decide to dump you as the programmer cause they can get a new person for 15% cheaper

Comment: @Oliver A.: I still think your best bet is to get a local test server going. Even with a restricted/limited testing environment you seem to be better off then with your hoster. Basically all you need is to get this one module running and throw the data at it, while monitoring the load. Despite that, I fear there isn't much we can do for you, unless somebody comes along who had the same problem and found a fix. well, one last thought comes to mind...if possible, try splitting the csv. Then you can at least figure out if it is the size of the file or a bug in the module (or both).

Comment: @Bobby Well I can not split the csv and right now we are having a hard time to set up an testing enviroment, becuase the ION Cube licensing file we have limits the use of the module to a specific server... but this whole thing is to complicated to discuss it online. THX anyway